# Importing modules from tuple (is this a bad idea?)

Tags: python, import, tuples

So my goal is to make my script easily transferable between servers.  That being the goal, I'd like to have my server automatically download any missing modules via pip.  To be concise, I thought of running it like this:

```
importTuple = (
    str("import "),
    (
        str("os"),
        str("sys"),
        str("time"),
        str("discord")
        )
    )
for i in range(len(importTuple[1])):
    try:
        exec(importTuple[0]+importTuple[1][i])
        print(importTuple[0]+importTuple[1][i]+" completed!")
    except ImportError:
        os.system("pip install "+importTuple[1][i])
        exec(importTuple[0]+importTuple[1][i])
```

I was wondering if this would be a huge negative in performance?  Or would it be exploitable?  Or would it even be better to just run a bunch of lines of Try/Except's?

Comment: `Or would it be exploitable?`... you bet.

Comment: Could I get an example as to how that could be achieved in this situation?

Comment: why not turn your own script into a package with a `requirements.txt` file

Comment: If you're going to attempt dynamic module importing, at least use `importlib`.

Comment: Not an answer, but those `str` calls are unnecessary, and `os`, `sys`, and `time` are all standard library modules - if you can't import them, something is deeply wrong and `pip` is not the solution.

Comment: @khan it's only *more* exploitable if some users can modify the tuples but not the script; as written anyone changing the tuples could equally easy re-code anything in the script-- it's not clear if user input is involved

Comment: The stated imports are more as an example, what I'd actually put in the tuple would be non-standard modules.

Comment: @Chris_Rands - For the importing portion, no user input will be accepted.  However, it'll be a discord bot eventually so Input will be read later on in the script; however none of those commands would touch the tuple (by my intention).

Comment: Unless this is running in a virtual environment, you have code running as a user that has write permission to system directories. That alone is probably a bad idea. Let your code do what it does, and let your system administrators do what they do (i.e., install code).

Comment: @chepner I appreciate it.  Thats pretty solid and straightforward advice.  I guess moral of the story is: Don't be lazy.

Comment: Your code, on the other hand, should be lazy. "Oh, I can't import `discord`? I give up; you guys fix it" :)

Comment: Appreciate it, thank you guys for the solid advice.